# Re-using previously Bitlocker encrypted SSD fails after formatting was aborted

Tags: partitioning, encryption, ssd

- In my other PC I had 2 identical Crucial MX 200 1 TB SSD drives which were both Bitlocker protected.
- I upgraded my other PC to NVM SSD and wanted to use them both old SSDs with Linux (Ubuntu 20.04).
- I removed them from the old PC and installed them in an external disk
  case (USB3) and both drives were found in KDE's partitionmanager
- I removed all found partitions on the drives and created new ext4
  partitions (I want to use them as storage) but when I applied the
  changes unfortunately partitionmanager crashed and the problems
  started.
- Now I am getting error messages in system-log whenever I connect one
  of the drives like:

> blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op
> 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
>
> blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op
> 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
>
> Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 256, async page read
>
> blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdd, sector 1953521536
> op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
>
> blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdd, sector 1953521536
> op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

- partitionmanager and gparted both can find the drives (after
  displaying some errors) but are not able to create new partitions (I
  can delete the old ones but when I try to create a new one and apply
  the changes I get "Input / Output Error")
- I also tried to clone another 1TB drive on one of them to perhaps fix
  issues with "initialization" - but it did not help - this is the
  command I used:

  ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/dev/disk2 conv=sync,noerror
  ```
- As I was running out of ideas I even tried if I could fix the problem
  in Windows with disk management but it did not work also (getting
  errors that data cannot be read / written).
- I looked into
  https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/diskpart-windows-10-1203.html and
  tried to "clean" the drives with diskpart - no success.
- I also checked the SMART data on both drives but according to the
  tool provided by Crucial "Crucial Storage Executive" both drives are
  in good shape and there were no issues.
- One thing that caught my eye under Windows was that there is an error
  in Windows System log mentioning the Bitlocker-Driver "The    device
  has a bad block" - could it be that the issue is somehow    related
  to the fact that the drives were Bitlocker encrypted? But no    other
  tool found bad blocks on the drive and how could I fix it?

Does anybody have an idea how I could re-resurrect the drives?
Is it really possible that the formatting error killed both drives in    a way that they cannot be fixed?
I also checked the external disk cases and with other drives they    work perfectly fine - so I don't think they are the problem.
I highly doubt that both SSDs (which worked fine in the first place)    are both now having a hardware-issue at the same time just after the    problem with formatting them in the first place....

Comment: Have you tried the "Disks" application from a live session (Try Ubuntu)?    **For diagnostics, eliminate unnecessary variables**: take the drives out of the external enclosure and connect the drives using SATA or m.2 or however you had them installed before.  Failures when working with individual partitions could be a symptom of a bad format, or corrupted partition scheme- variables that don't help determine whether or not the disk itself is usable. A true pass/fail test is whether or not the disks can be formatted (as a whole) when all other variables have been removed.

Comment: I would place it back internal and perform a secure erase on it (the special ssd command). This is something like a factory reset for an SSD. Afterwards you can try it again in the external enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help - but [https://askubuntu.com/users/37881/robert's](https://askubuntu.com/users/37881/robert%27s) hint was the solution:
After placing it into the PC again I was able to create partitions and format them (but again only under Windows 10 for some reason).
However I put the drives in the external case again and now I can use them!
Thanks again for all your help!